# Is there a way to get out of the tutorial zone without the glider?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

The developers of Zelda said that the game is beatable in 15 minutes.

I guess this means that you don't have to do the 4 shrines and then get the paraglider to finish the game.

So is there a way to get out of the tutorial area without the glider?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is **impossible**. Even if you manage to get past the fog, the paraglider check is *hardcoded* in the Player object code.

The code looks like this:

```
if ( !sForceEnableGlidingAndSurfingAndGiveRupees && !sIsDungeon )
{
  if ( !hasParaglider(0) && 
       (x < -1600.0 || x > -350.0 || z < 1400.0 || z > 2400.0) )
  {
    player->field_2304_x = -1021.7286376953125;
    player->field_2308_y = 253.31527709960938;
    player->field_230C_z = 1792.6009521484375;
    // 奈落開始待ち translates to 'wait for abyss start' (= the voidout state)
    return AI_AIBase::changeState(this, "奈落開始待ち", 0LL);
  }
}
```

(If you want to see for yourself, this is at 0x710082EFE4 in version 1.5.0 on Switch.)

[image: Plateau zone]

Unlike Wind Waker's castle barrier, this time there is no collision or object you could clip through. It's a simple coordinate check that *always* runs and there is no way to glitch past this check since it is embedded in Link's actor code.

Comment: So every couple of frames probably, it checks that you have the glider and if you dont and are out of the coordinates, you are voided out?

Comment: Likely several times per second and at least on every frame since this is part of the core actor code. And yep, if you don't have the glider and have had coordinates, you get immediately voided out.

Comment: Where did you get the Japanese-commented disassembly from?

Comment: From the Switch 1.5.0 executable. The Japanese string is an internal state string.

Comment: Just reread the code, and there would, theorically, be a way. If you could, in some way, put one of the 2 debug flags to true, you could get out of the starting area without the glider. Now the thing is, how could you do it?

Comment: Whoops, I forgot to update this post after figuring out what the two flags do. What I called "debug flag 1" is a flag that forces enable "gliding" and "surfing" and gives you 100 rupees, so it seems to be some dev mode only flag. There's no way to set it during normal gameplay. The second flag turned out to just be "is dungeon" -- whether you're in a shrine. There's no way to set that flag while you're in the main world either.

Comment: @Fredy31 (some more information) here is the (only) function where sIsDungeon (the second) is set, and what it's set to: https://gist.github.com/leoetlino/c3e625367affc6a2dadffb9c92d73f6f

Comment: Wow. Debugflag2 is a garbage variable name for that. Would get isInDungeon would be better.

Comment: @Fredy31 yeah, sadly I hadn't collected enough information on the code to give it a proper name back then. I'll edit my post now. (Just to be clear, all of the variable names are unofficial and they are only more or less informed guesses from me, as BotW is a game that shipped without any debugging symbols, which means all functions and variables are _unnamed_.)

Comment: Ah ok lol, tought you just took the code from the decompiled source in itself. Found it funny that the Big N would use such bad variable names :p You simply not knowing what both these variables did makes so much more sense in context.

Comment: If there was a way to glitch out of a shrine, leaving `isDungeon = true`

Answer (score 10):

No, it is not possible to leave without the glider. As mentioned by multiple users in [this thread](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/189707-the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/75087623), the glider is not necessary to descend, however, the fog that prevents you from leaving will not dissipate until you obtain the glider. That is, once you've *already obtained* the glider, it seems that you can descend the plateau without it, but you can't avoid actually getting it.

> The real problem is not physically leaving the Plateau, it's the fog that makes you despawn. The paraglider removes the fog, this video doesn't leave the Plateau (the map is available both at launch and landing)
>
> Have you even played the game? You cannot leave the plateau without completing the first four shrines and obtaining the glider. Its not the height of the plateau that stops you leaving, its the invisible barrier of fog surrounding it.

The video that spawned that particular discussion is [here](https://twitter.com/venick409/status/839533795862786048), and even there, the *person who posted the video* [commented that this does not negate the need for the glider](https://twitter.com/Venick409/status/839553436039413761):

> Nah. You need the glider to despawn the void out area around the plateau. If you could get past that you can skip it.

Comment: To give an idea of how incredibly pervasive the fog is and how absolutely impossible it is to skip Plateau, the fog is literally everywhere on the map. Even if you could get to the final fight room, the fog would still be there and it would force you back to the Plateau.

Comment: You can ride on a stasis'd object far enough to escape the death fog but there's actually a death cube around the plateau to stop you if you managed to get that far. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6izOPhysy5g